# Why is selector not displaying the pressed state

Tags: android, xml

Button style XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item>
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle"
            >
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp"
                />
            <gradient
                android:angle="0"
                android:startColor="#FF63a34a"
                android:endColor="#FF477b36"
                android:type="linear"
                />
            <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:top="50dp"
        >

        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle"
            >
            <solid
                android:color="#40000000"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Button style pressed XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item>
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle"
            >
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp"
                />
            <gradient
                android:angle="0"
                android:startColor="#FF63a34a"
                android:endColor="#FF63a34a"
                android:type="linear"
                />
            <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#4F5B5D" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Button style selector XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_round_style_pressed" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_round_style_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_round_style"></item>

</selector>
```

AlertDialog custom XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/button_round_style_selector"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/home_white"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How come when I press the LinearLayout, the selector isn't working correctly? It is not changing the drawable to the pressed state.

Comment: Do you have an onClickListener for you linear layout? Because it's not clickable according to your AlertDialog XML file.

Comment: No onClickListener, but shouldn't the background change based on the XML regardless of the listener, since it is not a button?

Comment: try making your LinearLayout clickable by adding `android:clickable="true"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinearLayout` is not clickable by default and its background won't change unless you put `clickable` tag true for it, or assign an `OnClickListener` to it.